# Android horizontal page scrolling

Tags: android

So I am making an application that has a "tips" section on a layout. I envision a section on the screen that shows one tip at a time where you can swipe left or right to see the next/previous tip. How would I go about doing that? Is there some builtin widget/layout that will help me with this?

Comment: you can use a viewpager

Comment: You can use HorizontalScrollView

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a ViewPager from the support library.  Here is the documentation: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html

Comment: Hey thanks! It doesn't show that in android studio so I had to look it up. Exactly what i was looking for.